# ExcelDna, rename the output XXX-packed.xll in existing project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, packaging, excel-dna

I've developed an ExcelDNA Addin in C#, VS2019. Before the deployment to the customers, I would like to rename the packed xll output of the project.
Right now, my project outputs 2 files (names are just for this example):

- MyAddin-packed.xll
- MyAddin64-packed.xll

Now I want to change the name of the output to `CoolAddin-packed.xll`.

Looks like `ExcelDnaBuild.exe` is completely ignoring following changes I did (the output is still MyAddin-packed.xll):

- Changed the Output Assembly name in the VS project.
- Change the `AssemblyTitle` attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs`
- Changed the name in *.dna file that is included in the project.

  ```
  <DnaLibrary Name="CoolAddinAddin" RuntimeVersion="v4.0">
  <ExternalLibrary Path="CoolAddinAddin.dll" ExplicitExports="false" 
  LoadFromBytes="true" Pack="true" />
  </DnaLibrary>
  ```

In addition, I dont see any tasks in PRE/POST build events that might be using the old name.

I am aware that the last solution might be to re-create the project skeleton and attach the files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps someone.

The base name for the packed file is the name of .dna file that is automatically generated by `NuGet Package Manager` install script of `Excel.Dna` package. `CoolAddin-Addin.dna` in this case.

So in this case, building the project will create 2 files:

- CoolAddin-Addin-packed.xll
- CoolAddin-AddIn64-packed.xll

If you rename the `CoolAddin-Addin.dna` file, it will rename the base of xll packed files.

[image]

Comment: You can also change other aspects of the output files, such as the `-packed` suffix, for example, by updating the file `ExcelDna.Build.props` inside of the folder `Properties`